# Java if statements in while loop is not working

Tags: java

So I'm trying to read the value the user inputs in `answerName` and then compare it with values I have stored beforehand but it seems it can't recognize the `if` in `while` loop.

Everything works. I'm able to read the string from the user and if a set the value on "room" outside of if it works. I tried searching but I couldn't find anything on this

```
int a=0;
while (a<rooms.length){
        String answerName = scanner.nextLine();
        if (rooms[a].name.equalsIgnoreCase(answerName)) {
            room = a;
            System.out.println(username +" have booked the " + rooms[room].name + " which is a " + rooms[room].type + " and it's on " + rooms[room].floor + " floor for " + cap + " people.");
            break;
        }
        a++;
}
```

I'm expecting to have this printed depending on the user answer `System.out.println(username +" have booked the " + rooms[room].name + " which is a " + rooms[room].type + " and it's on " + rooms[room].floor + " floor for " + cap + " people.");` but I always get the value from `rooms[1]`

this is a part of the whole program

```
  package com.company;

    import java.sql.SQLOutput;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;




    public class Room {

    private String name, type;
    private int capacity, floor;
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Room[] rooms;
    private static String[] time;

    public Room(String name, String type, int capacity, int floor) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.floor = floor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String answer = "y";
        String username;
        while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            rooms = new Room[9];
            time = new String[2];

            Room room1 = new Room("Taff, ", "small meeting, ", 8, 2);
            Room room2 = new Room("Llangrose, ", "large meeting, ", 24, 2);
            Room room3 = new Room("Pen, ", "teaching room, ", 70, 2);
            Room room4 = new Room("Usk, ", "small meeting, ", 8, 3);
            Room room5 = new Room("Bala, ", "large meeting, ", 24, 3);
            Room room6 = new Room("Cadair Idris, ", "teaching room, ", 70, 3);
            Room room7 = new Room("Wye, ", "small meeting, ", 8, 4);
            Room room8 = new Room("Gower, ", "open meeting/break-out space, ", 24, 4);
            Room room9 = new Room("Snowdon, ", "teaching room, ", 70, 4);

            rooms[0] = room1;
            rooms[1] = room2;
            rooms[2] = room3;
            rooms[3] = room4;
            rooms[4] = room5;
            rooms[5] = room6;
            rooms[6] = room7;
            rooms[7] = room8;
            rooms[8] = room9;
int something = 1;
            int cap = 0;
            System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
            username = scanner.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {

                System.out.println("Enter the time of booking: ");
                time[i] = scanner.next();

                System.out.println("Enter the amount of people:");
 cap = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("You booked for 1h starting at " + time[i]);
                System.out.println("Do you want to book for more time? If yes type 1 if no type 0");
                something = scanner.nextInt();
                if (something == 0) {
                    System.out.println("You have booked at " + time[0] + " your booking has a duration of 1h.");

                    break;
                } else if (something != 1 && something != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input");
                }
            }
            if (something == 1) {
                System.out.println("You have booked at " + time[0] + " and " + time[1] + " each booking has a duration of 1h.");
            }

                for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
                    if (rooms[i].capacity >= cap) {
                        System.out.println("The room " + rooms[i].name + " is available, which is " + rooms[i].type + " and it's on " + rooms[i].floor + " floor, and capacity of " + rooms[i].capacity);

                    }
                }
                System.out.println("please select the room of your choice ");

                int room = 0;
                int a = 0;
                String answerName = scanner.nextLine();
                while (a < rooms.length) {
                    if (rooms[a].name.equalsIgnoreCase(answerName)) {
                        room = a;
//                    System.out.println(username +" have booked the " + rooms[room].name + " which is a " + rooms[room].type + " and it's on " + rooms[room].floor + " floor for " + cap + " people.");
                    }
                    a++;
                }
                System.out.println(username + " have booked the " + rooms[room].name + " which is a " + rooms[room].type + " and it's on " + rooms[room].floor + " floor for " + cap + " people.");
System.out.println("Do you want to repeat the booking? If yes type y if no type n");
            answer = scanner.next();
 }
        }


    }
```

Comment: yes it happens because you are incrementing "a" variable at the end. so you are comparing answerName with new room[a] where a is incremented.

Comment: Please prepare a [mcve].

Comment: Did you intend `scanner.nextLine()` to be inside the loop like that?  To me, it would make more sense to call `scanner.nextLine()` just once, before the loop starts.

Comment: Is it possible your while loop simply never gets run? For instance rooms.length = 0?

Comment: I can put the whole code in but its 127 lines

Comment: Also, I have check it and it enters the while loop

Comment: The best way to solve this would be to step through with your debugger, and examine all the relevant variables at each point in the processing.  I'm sure it will only take a few minutes to find out what's going on.

Comment: i edited the post and i put a part of the whole code

Comment: the same happens with for loop i can enter the loop but it never enters the if statement

Comment: @PritsRamani where I should be incrementing "a"?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enter "Taff" as room name otherwise it won't be equal to room[a].name

Comment: can you explain it a little? because I got confused. thank you

Comment: String answerName = scanner.nextLine(); Here you should enter "Taff" when prompted for input. 
rooms[a].name.equalsIgnoreCase(answerName).. so that this "Taff".equals("Taff) will be equal and it will enter into if loop

Comment: yeah but if I enter Pen for example it still shows Taff

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, apparently when I was creating the object for the "name" I put "," and " ". the rest of the code is correct.